# Problems installing the Python library

Tags: python, visual-studio, pip

I'm trying to install "fatiando" library on Python 3.7.7
but everytime obtain some error.
I think, may be error in the Microsoft Visual Studio, but I don't understand what it is exactly. cmake already installed.
How to fix it?
Please, help

```
Writing C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2p57q5q2\fatiando-0.5\setup.cfg
Running fatiando-0.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2p57q5q2\fatiando-0.5\egg-dist-tmp-lxhnyiyk
_ttime2d.c
d:\python 377\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(2444): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(4796): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from '__int64' to 'long', possible loss of data
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(18342): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(18343): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(18344): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(18345): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(18346): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(18347): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19000): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19001): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19002): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19014): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19015): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19016): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19017): error C2039: 'exc_type': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19018): error C2039: 'exc_value': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
fatiando\seismic\_ttime2d.c(19019): error C2039: 'exc_traceback': is not a member of '_ts'
d:\python 377\include\pystate.h(212): note: see declaration of '_ts'
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Comment: Do you have a python interpreter at `d:\\python39\\python.exe`?

Comment: @SyntaxRules yes

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '-G', generator, cmake_dir])
...
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

You need to install cmake

https://cmake.org/install/

Or add it to the PATH, if it's already installed

Comment: Cmake can't find Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64. What kind of VS do you have installed?

Comment: VS 2019. There are links in the path on 2019 version
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx64\x64
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin